# How can i study the monotony of a trignometric function? $8\sin(x)+4\sin(2x)$

Tags: calculus

The first derivative is $8\cos(x)+8\cos(2x)$ and the only zero on the given domain is $\frac \pi3$.
How can I study  the monotony and signal changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: note that $$\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1$$
you have to solve the equation
$$8\cos(x)+8(2\cos^2(x)-1)=0$$
this is a quadratic equation

Comment: Yes, i concluded that **8cos(x)+8cos(2x)** **8(cos(x)+2cos^2(x)−1)**, to see the signal change i am supposed to swap the variable with a higher or lower value of π/3 , however its always (+). I dont know what i am doing wrong

Comment: Sorry if i expressed myself wrong, i have already solved the equation , im trying to study the signal of that derivative  8cos(x)+8cos(2x), the zeros i already found.